# Duplicate Render png sequence problem

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, output, duplicate

I am rendering 2 different view layers 1 called "foreground" and 1 called "shadows". The purpose of this is that I can have 2 different png sequences were one only renders the shadows and one only renders the foreground, which makes final compositing easier in after effects. HOWEVER I am experiencing a problem, when I render I get 3 different png sequences. 2 of them are the ones I expected (foreground**framenumber**.png) and (shadow**framenumber**.png) but for some weird reason I also render a png sequence only called (**framenumber**.png) which is a duplicate render of the (foreground**framenumber**.png). I will now provide my Compositing tab and show the png sequences created.[image: ndoes][image: sequences created]

Comment: This is totally normal. Because when rendering animations, other than rendering single images, files are autosaved according to the settings in the _Output Properties_ (because it is not very comfortable to manually save each image of a sequence and even impossible if you render it directly as a video). When you have no prefix specified there, the images are just named with the frane numbers